# SceneKit camera rotation wrong although camera and nodes share origin

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am playing with SceneKit trying to make a star field. Here are some sample stars with coordinates:

```
Name: Alpheratz, X: 25.9746 Y: 0.951042 Z: 14.4613
Name: Caph, X: 8.60001 Y: 0.344589 Z: 14.4095
Name: Algenib, X: 115.664 Y: 6.68732 Z: 31.4421
Name: Ankaa, X: 19.0837 Y: 2.19828 Z: -17.4833
Name: Shedir, X: 37.9848 Y: 6.78448 Z: 58.3796
Name: Diphda, X: 27.5836 Y: 5.31046 Z: -9.11979
Name: 96 G. Psc, X: 7.25837 Y: 1.5555 Z: 0.686093
Name: Van Maanen's Star, X: 4.14696 Y: 0.903519 Z: 0.400348
Name: Cih, X: 79.8367 Y: 20.168 Z: 146.837
```

(coordinates are from the [HYG Database.](http://www.astronexus.com/hyg))

The SceneView is simply a full-window view added in the storyboard. Setup of the scene, camera etc. is like this:

```
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

Then for each star I do:

```
        let starGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(1.0))
        let starNode = SCNNode(geometry: starGeometry)
        starNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(star.cartesianX.floatValue, star.cartesianY.floatValue, star.cartesianZ.floatValue)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(starNode)
```

This produces some shaded spheres in the view but they appear to be in the wrong place and they rotate around a point somewhere to the right of the screen.

What I expect to see is all the spheres rotating around the camera. As they move they should not change apparent size or swing away from the camera which is what they do. As more stars are plotted it gets harder to find anything to see even when fully zoomed out and as soon as a pan is applied everything disappears.

How can the camera be fixed at the origin and all the objects be positioned around the origin so that they rotate around that point?

Comment: Do you mean to use orthographic projection (no perspective)?

Comment: Should it matter here? I have tried both ways but it is only cosmetic, spheres remain as spheres or become elongated with perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I expect to see is all the spheres rotating around the camera. As they move they should not change apparent size or swing away from the camera which is what they do. As more stars are plotted it gets harder to find anything to see even when fully zoomed out and as soon as a pan is applied everything disappears.

how is you camera behaviour implemented?
You should definitely not rely on `allowsCameraControl`, which is a convenience to get started rapidly.

Comment: That's it - I found eulerAngles to be a convenient way of moving the camera once allowsCameraControl was disabled. Also, adding a look at constraint to the camera does not help when free movement is desired.